# Как сделать размер шрифта жирный 14?

Tags: php, css

```
$rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros);
echo("<div style='font size="4";'>"$rez['nazv']);
echo($rez['text']);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo "<div style='font-size:14px; font-weight: bold;'>{$rez['nazv']}</div>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<DIV STYLE="font-size:14px; font-weight: bold">
```

Comment: не хочет
`
<div style='font-size:12px; font-weight: bold'>"$rez['nazv'] </div>
`
пишет
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\xampplite\htdocs\bol\vivod.php on line 8

Comment: ну это значит где-то скорее всего ошиблись с кавычками.
скопируйте сюда всю строку начиная с ECHO.

Comment: css не выдает Parse error.

Answer (score 2):

Вот очень полезный [ресурс](http://htmlbook.ru/) для такого рода вопросов... Непосредственно вашу проблему нужно решать так

```
style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;"
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

`echo "<div style='font size=14px; font-weight: bold'>".$rez['nazv']."</div>";`

Answer (score 2):

А в чем, собственно, вопрос?

```
$rez=mysql_fetch_array($zapros);
echo('<div style="font-size: 14; font-weight: bold;">'.$rez['nazv']);
echo($rez['text']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Знаешь, есть такой тег. `<font>` называется....

Comment: Я русскими написал, потому что хэшкод не отображает.

Comment: Знаешь, есть на хэшкоде есть кнопочка с нулями и единицами...

Comment: Не понимаю к чему это высказывание?....

Comment: @new_russian_man Чтобы код отформатировался, выделите его мышью и нажмите кнопку 101010.